# Android limit max activity stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an android app with around 50 activities.

Currently I have implemented the default behavior i.e. when a user starts a new activity I simply put the existing one in stack and do not remove is until user presses back.

I like this because a user can go back to his last activity by pressing back anytime..

Now the problem with this is the OutOfMemory Errors after on devises with less memory..

One solution I can find is to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` which as explained in the documentation would remove activities on top of last entry of the called activity from the stack.. e.g. if the stack has A->B->C->D and is user goes to B C and D are removed from the stack. **My problem with this solution is that if now user clicks back he'll goto A while he might be expecting to goto D..**

***My Question***: Is there any way to define a max limit on the activity stack? i.e. If I define 15, only max of 15 activities will be there in the stack, on 17th activity start it'll remove the 1st activity from the stack automatically and will maintain 2nd to 16th in stack, if I start 18th it'll have 3rd to 17th in stack..

Comment: The Android framework does not have a way for you to configure the size of the activity stack. Basically you will need to manage this yourself.

Comment: @DavidWasser thnx for reply.. Can u help me about how to remove activities from stack.. I can find answers to get the size..

Comment: You could have each activity register a `BroadcastReceiver` and when it is time to "cleanup", you send a broadcast `Intent`. Each activity's `BroadcastReceiver` will then get the broadcast, check if it should quit, and if so, call `finish()`. Something like that could work. On the other hand, perhaps your architecture is broken. 50 activities sounds like an awful lot for even a non-trivial application.